# How split array with regular expression with references

Tags: php, regex, arrays, preg-replace

I need split string by comma, but comma shouldn`t be inside square brackets. For example string:

```
'"f2140202585",true,"some, str","numeric","MegapixNum","","","0.3,16.0","0.3,16","17",2,""'
```

Should produce this result:

```
['"f2140202585"', 'true', '"some, str"', '"numeric"', '"MegapixNum"', '"0.3,16.0"', '"0.3,16"', '"17"', '2', '""']
```

I know that preg_replace function exists for this, but i cant figure out what regexp should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve it this way:

```
preg_match_all('/("[^"]+?"|[^\,]+)/', $faq, $matches);
```